# Cross platform network status detection for Android and iOS - if not: how to implement on Android?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have been using [Reachability](http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/network/reachability/detect_if_network_is_available/) for network status detection on iOS and [this](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html) for Android. However I'm wondering if there is a cross platform alternative I have overlooked so far?

In a perfect world, it would support the following on both platforms:

- Check if network is up
- Check if it is WiFi or 3G
- Check if a specific server can be reached  (Ping)
- Optionally: trigger a callback if network status changes

Doing it in plain .NET would probably not fire up the network correctly (on iOS at least).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Android the `ConnectivityManager` class in the one that does more or less the same as Reachability on iOS.

Unfortunately there are no cross-platform libraries that encapsulates these as far as I know.

Actually, this sounds like a fun open source project if you have the time :-) You should be able to write a common library that behaves the same on both iOS and Android that wraps the Reachability and ConnectivityManager libraries.

Comment: Would still require to separate packages, one for each platform. Plus one common interface. But yeah, doable. Time? We'll see. I need the functionality. Might share it.

Comment: Yep. It would take some time, but it would be both useful and interesting.